# How do I make a graph for server uptime and downtime as shown in the image

Tags: jquery, graph

How do I make a graph like in the image in link below. A script is run every 5 minutes on server which checks if server is up or down. I've file which has datetime stamp and the status as 1/0 for up and down. Now I need to make a graph same as in the image.

[Graph image link](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0ce4jfg8c8)

Status file looks like this:

```
Wed Mar 4 13:18:42 UTC 2015, Serverup
Wed Mar 4 13:23:42 UTC 2015, Serverup
Wed Mar 4 13:28:42 UTC 2015, Serverdown
Wed Mar 4 13:33:42 UTC 2015, Serverup
Wed Mar 4 13:38:42 UTC 2015, Serverup
Wed Mar 4 13:43:42 UTC 2015, Serverup
```

Comment: Maybe show us a few lines of your file? Maybe tell us what OS you use?

Comment: What has `jquery` got to do with it? Surely you would generate the graph as an image on the server in a cronjob and just pick that up with a straightforward <img> tag?

Comment: I've to show this graph in website. Normally the graphs shown in website are made using jQuery.

Comment: File contents are as under                                                                  Wed Mar  4 13:18:42 UTC 2015, Serverup                                              Wed Mar  4 13:23:42 UTC 2015, Serverup                                              Wed Mar  4 13:28:42 UTC 2015, Serverdown                                          Wed Mar  4 13:33:42 UTC 2015, Serverup                                           Wed Mar  4 13:38:42 UTC 2015, Serverup                                        Wed Mar  4 13:43:42 UTC 2015, Serverup

Comment: Its a linux base OS. A script runs every five minutes and write in the file the status of server with current time stamp

Comment: It's better to click `edit` underneath your question and update it clearly for all to see rather than pasting a load of code into the `comment` area where it is hard to read.

Comment: Personally, I would change the job that runs every 5 minutes to check the status to make it generate the graph as well at the same time (using `gnuplot` or similar) and then just have a static link to the generated plot/image in your HTML.

Comment: I can't place a link.The user requirement is to show the graph on web page. I've seen jQuery horizontal bar graphs. As shown in the image I need to make a single horizontal bar graph which based on data shows green colour when server is up and changes its colour to red when server is down.

Comment: And there is just x-axis no y-axis. The x-axis has the date. And the bar changes colour if server is up or down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would generate the image anew on the server each time you determine its UP/DOWN status, using ImageMagick. It is installed on most Linux distros and available for OSX and Windows.

Here is little script that makes the image, then you would just pick up that image in your HTML. It is pretty well commented so you can see what it is doing:

```
#!/bin/bash
blockw=8    # width of up/down block
blockh=20   # height of up/down block
datew=100   # width of field containing date
dateh=60    # height of field containing date
xpos=0      # current output position

# Generate key to colours (BLUE part of explanatory image)
convert -background none -gravity west -pointsize 36 \
   -size 60x60 xc:green                              \
   -size 300x60 label:"Server UP"                    \
   -size 60x60 xc:red                                \
   -size 300x60 label:"Server DOWN" +append key.png

# Parse server status file
while read junk day date rest; do
   day="$day $date"

   # Set colour, green for up, and overwrite with red if down
   colour="green"
   [[ $rest == *"own"* ]] && colour="red"

   # Just output our standard red/green status block  (YELLOW part of explanatory image)
   convert -size ${blockw}x${blockh} xc:$colour miff:-

   # If day has changed, remember day for next time, and output it too
   if [ "$day" != "$prevday" ]; then
      prevday=$day

      # Create our label for today
      convert -size ${datew}x${dateh} -background none -pointsize 36 label:"$day" today.png

      if [ $xpos -eq 0 ]; then
         # Create very first datebar file
         mv today.png datebar.png
         datex=$datew
      else
         # Second or subsequent date, append to datebar file at correct position (MAGENTA part of explanatory image)
         ((xpad=xpos-datex))
         convert -background none datebar.png -size ${xpad}x${dateh} xc:none today.png +append datebar.png

         # Keep track of width of datebar
         ((datex=datex+xpad+datew))
      fi
   fi

   # Keep track of our x position
   ((xpos+=blockw))
done < status.csv | convert -background white - +append \
    datebar.png -append                                 \
   -gravity center -extent 110x600%                     \
   -gravity South key.png -composite result.png
```

Here is what it makes:

[image]

Just to explain, in case you don't know ImageMagick that well, the image is formed in 3 parts, coloured in blue, yellow and magenta in the diagram below. I have labelled the code to show which part is being generated at each place.

[image]

Comment: I tried it on my ubuntu 14.04 and got these on the terminal               convert.im6: unable to acquire cache view `No such file or directory' @ fatal/cache-view.c/AcquireAuthenticCacheView/121.
convert.im6: unable to acquire cache view `No such file or directory' @ fatal/cache-view.c/AcquireAuthenticCacheView/121.

Comment: The output image file links are Result.png (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9seSsqMTwxTY1VBc2t1VEwtSFk&authuser=0) today.png (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9seSsqMTwxTVTdfSVd5ZHo0SVU&authuser=0) key.png (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9seSsqMTwxTb0NpQmFJdmRLLVk&authuser=0) datebar.png (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9seSsqMTwxTWjVhTGJWR0Ffak0&authuser=0)

Comment: Thank you I didn't know Imagemagick. I got it now. I used the file you created, removed the dots. But still the output isn't complete. Can you please view the images I shared.

Comment: The `status.csv` file I showed isn't complete - I chopped pieces out to make it fit on StackOverflow. You will need to adapt the line that starts `while IFS=...` so that it matches your file format.

Comment: Hold on, I'll do it for you.

Comment: Output not correct. Please view; am I making some mistake? graph.sh (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9seSsqMTwxTMk5jY0Fma0tkWmM/view?usp=sharing) status.csv (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9seSsqMTwxTMjcxYmtMVGRUdDQ/view?usp=sharing) result.png (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9seSsqMTwxTaU1rOW1iWU5ibDQ/view?usp=sharing) today.png (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9seSsqMTwxTaU92eWVKWFQ3b3M/view?usp=sharing) key.png (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9seSsqMTwxTN0xQRDZJOU1WT1U/view?usp=sharing) datebar.png (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9seSsqMTwxTdEpSY2l2dUFta0E/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You need to use your own `status.csv` in the format you described in your question.

Comment: It worked now. But the images are not complete. Please view the images. Where am I mistaken. datebar.png (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9seSsqMTwxTbFI3dm82N1IxUUk/view?usp=sharing), key.png (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9seSsqMTwxTTVF1WjVSYnhvbEU/view?usp=sharing) result.png (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9seSsqMTwxTd2loSTlHQ2Rnd2M/view?usp=sharing) today.png (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9seSsqMTwxTam50QjJoaWNRZHM/view?usp=sharing) and status.csv (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9seSsqMTwxTV3htRml5WFpveUU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I still get this on terminal convert.im6: unable to acquire cache view No such file or directory' @ fatal/cache-view.c/AcquireAuthenticCacheView/121.

Comment: According to your question, your log file should have one entry every 5 minutes but they don't! So there is not enough space to fit the date before the next day shows up. One entry every five minutes makes 288 entries per day, which will make 288 blocks of 8 pixels each, which means I will have space for the 100 pixel wide day/date underneath. If you only have 5 entries per day, that will only take 5 * 8 (i.e. 40 pixels of width) so there is no room for the 100 pixel wide date underneath the day. Use proper logs please!

Comment: Thank you it worked. But the image is so wide. How do I scale it to a size like you have in the images above or even smaller than this? Because in one time I'll show 1 week data. I reduced the size in html but then the graph became so small to be visible.

Comment: At the moment, `blockw` is 8, so the image will get 8 pixels wider for every line in your log file. Either reduce the `8` to `7`, or `6` or `5` etc, or reduce the number of days of data you pass in from your log file, or do some mixture of these two things.

Comment: It worked thank you. I've changed the status file now it will check status every 15 minutes. I've changed the script and it works fine now.

Comment: But there is a problem that the file will keep on increasing everyday. 96 entries per day and 672 entries per week. I just want to use last 7 days data from status.csv How would I do this?

Comment: Run `tail -672 YourFullLogFile > status.csv` before using my script, then it will only see the last 672 lines of your log.

Comment: Can I use the hex or rgb colour value instead of simply using red or green ?

Comment: Sure, just put it in double quotes like this `"rgb(255,0,0)"` or in hex `"#ff00aa"`

Comment: I know the question was asked almost 4 years ago, but do You know how this type of chart (bar) is called? I'm trying to find something like that for the web (using canvas) but I don't know how to name it :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what the people in server-rooms call it. Try Googling `mrtg` as they have some charts like that - maybe *"Server Availability Chart"*. I don't know - I am guessing!